# Where do I upload SP's XML in KeyCloak?

Tags: xml, upload, metadata, keycloak

I've downloaded the "installation" config file from Keycloak(IDP) and installed it in my application (SP) and I believe that I need to upload the metadata XML the SP produces back into Keycloak.

Can I find anywhere to upload a file? No.

Am I missing something obvious? I've been through all the screens in the client definition page. Looked at various documentation etc.

It looks like it should be on the installation tab, but all the buttons say "download" not "upload".

Answer (score 1):

It appears you need to upload the XML when creating the client. You can't create the client and upload it later. On the client create screen there is an upload button.

(Thanks to Stian Thorgersen on the keycloak users mailing list for this one)